# How to determine or delete all unused embedded resources in C# Windows Forms Application?

Tags: c#, .net

I'm making a C# Windows Forms Application that uses a large number of embedded resources(images,icons,...).After a long time editing,adding and removing objects from forms , many resources are not used at current time.I tried to delete unused resources myself but i found it too hard to do that as i can't remember all unused resources in my project.Is there an easy way to find or delete unused resources from my project ?

Comment: I think EgyEast is talking about the Application Resources i.e. images, strings, icons etc. Am I right?

Comment: You'll have to be a bit more organized about it.  VS does ultimately assume that you know what you are doing, it certainly won't automatically delete a resource for you. The tool you need is the one between your ears.  Same old story :)

Comment: Are you looking for a tool to delete unused resources from the project folder in Visual Studio? (not resource objects, like a Font, used in your C# code)

Comment: sorry for inadequate explanation of my problem but i mean embedded resources like images or icons

Answer (score 1):

You should ensure all of those resources are implementing [IDisposable](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.idisposable.aspx) and use them from within a `using()` block.

Example from [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yh598w02%28v=vs.80%29.aspx):

```
using (Font font1 = new Font("Arial", 10.0f))
{
   //font1 will have it's Dispose() method automatically called afterwards
}
```

This way you never have to remember to dispose of those resources, as they will happen automatically.

Don't forget the Garbage Collector will also clear out objects which are no longer referenced, it's the beauty of coding within a managed environment!

Comment: sorry for inadequate explanation of my problem but i mean embedded resources like images or icons

Comment: Question is about resources files/strings in VS not a running program.